# Jenkins: get build info of deeper levels downstreamed jobs

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

The main parent job A triggers downstreamed job B in the steps. It's easy to get build info of job B once it's done, because it's already defined. However, on Jenkins, job B starts its own downstreamed job C, which is in no way defined in job A stages.

Is there a way to get back job C info in the job B step?

I want to send an email containing job A, job B and job C info, but I can't find a way to get job C info.

Comment: Do you have a pipeline definition file you could share so we can see how jobs are set up?

Comment: Yea it’s possible and I wrote something very similar for the exact same reason. How are you getting Job B’s build log, and why are you saying it’s harder to get Job C’s?  I ask because I don’t mind writing an answer but I would like know where you’re stuck so I can tailor the answer accordingly. I’m assuming by “job C info” you mean you want the build log ( or parts of the build log )?